# Setting up a virtual host on XAMPP on Mac

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

I am trying to set up a virtualhost on my apple mac on localhost. The server is provided by XAMPP, which bundles Apache/MySQL/PHP in one bundle.

Here is what I have done so far:

Edited /private/etc/hosts to include 127.0.0.1 to point to test.myserver.local

```
127.0.0.1       test.myserver.local
```

Edited /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf to inlcude my vhosts details

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /Users/???/Documents/workspace/trunk/htdocs
   ServerName test.myserver.local
  <Directory "/Users/???/Documents/workspace/trunk/htdocs">
     AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Placed a simple index.html in there with the word test in it.

I have restarted the server, and then browse to the test url to be greeted with Apache's default page instead of my test page.
The vhosts file works for another virtual host, the code is copied with the respective bits changed (i.e. folder paths), the hosts file works, as when Apache is turned off, my browser says server not found.

Why is Apache refusing to show up my test code? Are there any other files I need to change? I cant think of any others, its usually just those on linux/windows.

Comment: Can you show us what you have edited in `/private/etc/hosts`, `/Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and update it in the question? Did you restart the Apache server after editing them?

Comment: You restarted apache afterwards right?

Comment: I tried, but it seems to remove all my tags, so it doesnt look good. I'll try again.

Comment: @prodigitalson absolutely. I've done this a fair few times, so Im a little stumped.

Comment: I once heard that there was a problem with certain versions of XAMPP if you didn't leave the localhost vhost entry in there... You might want to try adding that back.  Long shot, but maybe... :)

Comment: Maybe the virtualhost config isn't loaded in the first place. Something like `Include /Applications/XAMPP/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` could be commented out in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: It certainly is loaded. Apache complains if theres a typo in the file.

Comment: I've *sometimes* had problems with using a name that ends with `.local`.  Are your other vhosts also in the `.local` top-level or are they something else?  If they are something else, make this one something else too.

Comment: can you try to use another port, let's say 8080. Maybe there is a conflict of more than one site configured with the same port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you told Apache to actually use name-based virtual hosting?

```
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

I don't believe it's enabled by default in Xampp on Mac.

Comment: Yes, it is already set up for some of the other virtual hosts and they work. Thanks anyway. Always good to have a second pair of eyes.

Comment: @Danack where exactly does this option go? in the `http-vhosts.conf`?

Answer (score 9):

On xampp you need to edit 3 files to setup virtual hosts

the /etc/hosts and /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf as you did.

But also you need to edit /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf to include the http-vhosts.conf

make sure you have uncommented this line

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

EDIT

Have you tried to add this lines

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Just before the

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Like I've said this file is already included. I have other virtualhosts in there that work.

Comment: what is the 3rd file you have to edit? you just mentioned 2 like the previous method

Comment: it is the hosts file!

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving the the setting for "localhost" at the end of the file "httpd-vhosts.conf",
i.e.:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
...

# others vhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
</VirtualHost>

# localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#end of httpd-vhosts.conf file
```

Worked for me, greetings!